# Finding the slope at two points.

Tags: calculus, functions, polynomials, derivatives

I have been sitting at this for 2 days and I'm not getting anywhere, admittedly I might be just very dumb when it comes to mathematics, and as such I would really appreciate some help with this. I have two columns of data in excel, depth and concentration of iron, so I have x=depth and y=concentration. I have graphed it and overlayed it with a polynomial line of 3rd degree. The line starts at (0,0). I have also got the equation of the line from excel being:

y = -0.64220x^3 + 4.8741x^2 + 0.13181x + 0.039473

Now I am to find the slope (gradient) at 2m depth and 4m depth. Since depth is on the x-axis, I assume that the 2m depth is x=2 and 4m depth is x=4. Now there are empty X and Y fields which I assume I am to fill with the coordinates, so XY for 2m depth would be x=2 and y=f(2) and for 4m depth x=4 and y=f(4). That's all that I have been able to do so far, I have also differentiated the f(x) but don't know what to do next... How to find the slope at those two points? Please help :-(

Comment: As I understand the problem, you want to use the derivative $f'(x)$ to find the depth. That's correct, but you will need to evaluate $f'(x)$ in a given point, i.e., the slope in $x=2$ equals $f'(2)$.

Comment: I don't know what to use to find the slope. I believe that in order to find a slope of point on a curve, you have to use derivatives, is that correct? In this case, do I just take the equation written in my OP, plug in x=2 and differentiate? Is that going to give me a number that would be the slope of that exact point sitting above depth 2m (above x=2)?

Comment: If you plug in $x=2$, you get a number; if you then differentiate, you get zero. Differentiate first, then plug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
f(x) = -0.64220x^3 + 4.8741x^2 + 0.13181x + 0.039473
\\f'(x) = -3\times0.64220x^2 + 2 \times 4.8741x + 0.13181
\\f'(2) = -3\times0.64220\times 2^2 + 2 \times 24.8741\times 2 + 0.13181
$$
and similarly for $f'(4)$

Comment: Ok, so I did that and now I am left with:

f'(2) = 11.92181
and
f'(4) = 8.29901

But what do I do now? Are these the values of slope for x=2 and x=4?

Comment: Yes.  The slope of the curve at $x = 2$ is $f'(2)$.  More generally, the slope of the curve at $x = c$ is $f'(c)$ provided $f'(c)$ exists.

Comment: Ok so no need to use this equation dy = f (x + dx) - f (x) at all for the slope? And what does the (c) denote?

Comment: c is here used as a symbol for an arbitrary real number (the c stands for constant)